# How to manually add public nodes to your node?

Tags: monerod, peer-discovery, peer, bitmonero-conf

I want to add peers from a list to my monero node in addition to the nodes to which I am already connected or are connected to me.

I'm using `monerod.conf` file and add remote nodes (found [here](https://moneroworld.com)) to the end:

```
add-peer=opennode.xmr-tw.org:18089
add-peer=node.moneroworld.com:18089
#add-peer=node.xmrbackb.one:18081
add-peer=uwillrunanodesoon.moneroworld.com:18089
add-peer=node.xmr.to:18081
add-peer=nodes.hashvault.pro:18081
add-peer=node.supportxmr.com:18081
```

But after requesting `get_connections` to rpc node I don't see ip peers added by me from the list above.

Does `--add-peer` not work in the config file and  only as separate parameters when starting the daemon?

**UPD**: I'm trying using --add-peer as parameter and still can't see peers from the list above in response of `get_connections` request...

```
/usr/local/bin/monerod --config-file /etc/monero/monerod.conf \
    --detach --non-interactive --pidfile /run/monero/monerod.pid \
    --add-peer  opennode.xmr-tw.org:18089 \
    --add-peer  uwillrunanodesoon.moneroworld.com:18089 \
    --add-peer  node.xmr.to:18081 \
    --add-peer  nodes.hashvault.pro:18081 \
    --add-peer  node.supportxmr.com:18081
```

And another question, will the list of nodes to which my node has an incoming or outgoing connection will be saved and used when rebooting the daemon? Did I understand correcyly that the list of peers is stored in `p2pstate.bin` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... --add-peer  node.supportxmr.com:18081

`--add-peer arg` is the correct parameter, however, by the peers you are trying to add it's clear you are using the other peers **RPC** interface, not their **p2p** interface. The p2p port is **18080**.

`--add-peer arg` is for adding p2p peers.

Also,

> But after requesting get_connections to rpc node ...

You can check which peers your node is currently connected to with the `monerod` command `print_cn`, which will show all the inbound and outbound connected peers.

> And another question, will the list of nodes to which my node has an incoming or outgoing connection will be saved and used when rebooting the daemon?

Yes.

Comment: Yes, my mistake was incorrect port, I need more cofee..  Thanks! Is this the only way to add peers (using `--add-peer`)? Is it possible to add a peer manually without restarting the daemon?

Comment: There's no add_peer command, just config file / command line parameter. So you'd have to restart if you want to manually specify peers.